# htaccess rewrite rule from /index.php to /index AND from ?lang=en to /en/ NOT WORKING

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a htaccess file which removes the .php extension from my url. It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I would like to add another RewriteRule which would modify my url from this:

www.example.com/index **?lang=en**

to this:

www.example.com **/en/** index

The code I came up with looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(de|en)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?lang=de [L,QSA]
```

This works on my local XAMPP server, but not on my hosted webhosting server.

What could cause the problem, is it the code, or is the .htaccess file cached in my browser?

Isn't this code compatible with my webhosting?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding,

```
Options -MultiViews
```

On top of your rules.

Comment: Please try it after clearing your browser cache and even if not working please try after restarting apche.

Comment: I cleared the cache, and I even tried another browser. Unfortunately, it's technically impossible to restart my web hosting server. Do you have any other idea, on what's causing the problem? Maybe the server refreshes the .htaccess file periodically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(de|en)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ $1?lang=de [L,QSA]
```